# how to load url into windows by jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I want to go to url on an element click event, here is my code :

```
$('#job').click(function() {  
        window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->createUrl('jobs/view');?>";
    });
```

but the url is loaded as `http://mysite/<?php echo $this->createUrl('jobs/view');?>` instead of `http://mysite/jobs/view`, so the php script didn't run, how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: is this in a .js file or a .php file? If your web server isn't configured to parse .js files as php, it won't work.

Comment: don't dump php output directly into a JS context. you'll kill the entire JS block if the output contains any JS metachars. always output via `json_encode()`, to prevent the JS-equivalent of sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your filename from `yourfile.js` to `yourfile.php` and wrap the whole JS code inside `script` tag.

Comment: Nitpick: OP may not need to wrap the code inside of a script tag.. he can use `<script src="myfile.php" type="text/javascript">` as long as `myfile.php` is served with the correct MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use PHP to make the URL.  Just use

```
$('#job').click(function() {  
        window.location.href = "/jobs/view";
    });
```